# How to find all token holders?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, addresses, tokens

For example, the contract saves the address when token created but after that token holder could send token or all tokens to another wallet.

Is it possible to find all wallet addresses of token holders which were created by my contract?

Comment: very cool..
Any example of 'IDS IN ARRAY' along with get function to see them??
I'm not so familiar with mapping can't really get my head around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All token transfers are performed by calling methods on your contract - so your contract can track balances and accounts in any way it wishes. If you're using the default arrangement of using a Solidity `mapping`, you will also need to keep a separate list of known account IDs in an array, so you can iterate over them.

Comment: How to get on outside contract?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a standalone open source tool which does the same.

- Take a token contract address
- Iterate over all ERC-20 `Transfer` events for token using `eth_getLogs` JSON-RPC API
- Build a local database of these events
- Allow you to use SQL to query any account balance on any point of time (block num) - note that some balances may have become zero

[You can find the command line application how to build the database here](https://docs.tokenmarket.net/erc-20-holders.html)

[The core Python logic is here](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/sto/blob/master/sto/ethereum/scanner.py).

There are some quirks here and there: for example detecting mint / creation event for some tokens is not straightforward. Thus, you will may negative balance on the account receiving initial total supply if you rely on `Transfer` event only.

Comment: Wondering if this still works as I see docs page is giving 404 now, https://docs.tokenmarket.net/erc-20-holders.html ?

Answer (score -1):

You can watch the event as it happens within an app or within the token contract itself use:

```
mapping (uint => mapping (address => uint)) mappedAccounts;
```

Comment: That is not an event definition or an event emitter. Your answer is confusing. Perhaps you could add further information.

Comment: I think he intended some kind of inverted index like `mapping (address => uint)` and then `mapping (uint => address)` to track addresses, like Nick Johnson said.

Comment: I know this is ancient but I'm returning from a long battle with illness and coming back to life again! My response was rushed and has two suggestions, therefore unclear. 'Waching the event' is what @Mikko suggested. I added 'or'  add a mapping in the 'contract itself' which could be looped through to discover all addresses. Please consider removing downvote.