# how can I query to find all NFT token holders?

Tags: erc-20, airdrop

For preparing an Airdop, for example, I want to find all owners of a specific NFT contract at a set date (today is OK, just actual hodlers, not all previous owners).

In doing some digging most APIs seem to provide event listeners, so I would need to have a server out there constantly available and listening.

I can also see you could set up a subgraph on thegraph or other indexer and it would do the listening for you?

What are some other ways to do queries on the chain and filter for owners of a contract? It seems heavy duty to query/filter the whole blockchain.

Ideally I'm looking for JS/typescript code.

related questions and research below, really looking for advice on the best option here :D

- covalent allow sql queries to the chain
  https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#overview
- fetch all token transfer events
  https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events
- @graphprotocol
  does not seem to provide a historical API for this? so i would have to set this up as a subgraph in advance?
  https://thegraph.com/docs/developer/query-the-graph
- etherscan
  has an api for [ERC721 token transfer by address](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-erc721-token-transfer-events-by-address) but not total owners? this is per wallet.
- example scraping etherscan
  [API to gather list of top token holders](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41684/api-to-gather-list-of-top-token-holders)
- [How to find all token holders?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4295/how-to-find-all-token-holders)
- [How to make a snapshot of ERC-721 (NFT) token holders](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93883/how-to-make-a-snapshot-of-erc-721-nft-token-holders)
- [A list of token holders at a specific time](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36274/a-list-of-token-holders-at-a-specific-time/64814)
- python code to iterate and query (heavy)
  https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/sto/blob/master/sto/ethereum/scanner.py

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the authur is just asking for someone to write code for them

Comment: not really, i'm looking for advice on the best way to do it - with an indexer, or even adding a function to the contract to make it enumerable. I'm not sure of the trade offs from doing that - gas cost of keeping the data on-chain so its always available. its a common question, but actually quite deep in it's implications. There maybe a fn in ethers that handles this, but ERC721 doesn't afaik.

Comment: "Ideally I'm looking for JS/typescript code"

Comment: @dcsan This answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64814 is exactly what you are looking for. You even commented on it, why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the NFT id and iterate through it, 0 - n, calling
`owners.push(await tokenContract.ownerOf(i))`